Can't put each element in backtick
I am trying to put each attribute from the dictionary into a backstick to create a query out of it, however all I got is that it starts with a backstick and finish with a backstick despite all my efforts
base_datatypes = [
    {"datatype": 1, "data_type_name": "SomeValue"},
    {"datatype": 2, "data_type_name": "DateTime"},
]

datatype_attributes_dict = {
    "DateTime": "'Year','Month','Day'"
}

created_base_attributes = [
    "attribute_DateTimeTable",
    "attribute_SomeDictionary"
]

select_clause = "SELECT COALESCE(t1.sys_id, t2.sys_id) AS PK"

for i, view in enumerate(created_base_attributes, start=1):
    data_type_name = next((item["data_type_name"] for item in base_datatypes if f"attribute_{item['data_type_name'].lower()}" == view), None)
    if data_type_name:
        attributes = datatype_attributes_dict.get(data_type_name, "")
        if attributes:
            columns = [f"`{attr.strip()}`" for attr in attributes.replace("'", "").split(",")]
            select_clause += ", " + ", ".join(columns)

print(select_clause)

I got output like (despite SELECT COALESCE (..))
like
``Year,Month,Day``

I want it like
``Year``,``Month``,``Day``


Why do you have a comma-separated string in datatype_attributes_dict instead of a list?

E.g. "DateTime": ['Year','Month','Day']

Why do you want the backticks to be doubled like that?

I don't get the year/month/day in the output at all. Shouldn't attribute_DateTimeTable be attribute_DateTime?

I also needed to change view to view.lower(). Once I fix these mistakes, I get the proper result.

SELECT COALESCE(t1.sys_id, t2.sys_id) AS PK, `Year`, `Month`, `Day` 

I didn't provide whole snippet of code because its too long anybody would ever read. Basically I want that as coma separated because I'll construct SQL query out of it and those will be mine columns, attribute_datetimetable should be as it is, because it has datatype: 2, and previously I have query where I put this datatype, retrieve columns and store it into attribute_datetimetable, similary to attribute_somevaluetable

The elements of created_base_attributes have to match the data_type_name in fields in base_datatypes. So either attribute_DateTimeTable needs to be changed in created_base_attributes, or DateTime needs to be changed to DateTimeTable in base_datatypes.

The reason is When you split by ",", if there's a space after the comma, it becomes part of the resulting string.
``Year,Month,Day``

This means your attr.strip() call is only removing spaces at the very beginning and end of the entire string, not around the individual attributes after splitting.
I have tried the below approach:
base_datatypes = [
    {"datatype": 1, "data_type_name": "SomeValue"},
    {"datatype": 2, "data_type_name": "DateTime"},
]
datatype_attributes_dict = {
    "DateTime": "'Year','Month','Day'"
}
created_base_attributes = [
    "attribute_DateTime",
    "attribute_SomeValue"
]
select_clause = "SELECT COALESCE(t1.sys_id, t2.sys_id) AS PK"
for view in created_base_attributes:
    for item in base_datatypes:
        if f"attribute_{item['data_type_name']}" == view:
            data_type_name = item["data_type_name"]
            attributes = datatype_attributes_dict.get(data_type_name, "")
            if attributes:
                columns = [f"``{attr.strip()}``" for attr in attributes.replace("'", "").split(",")]
                select_clause += ", " + ", ".join(columns)
                break
print(select_clause)

Results:
SELECT COALESCE(t1.sys_id, t2.sys_id) AS PK, ``Year``, ``Month``, ``Day``

The above code iterates over the created_base_attributes list and checks if the attribute name matches with the data_type_name in the base_datatypes list.
If there is a match, it retrieves the attributes from the datatype_attributes_dict and creates the columns with backticks using a list comprehension.
The columns are then joined with a comma and added to the select_clause.
